# Error: The apk for your currently selected variant (Unknown output) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (release)

Tags: android, android-studio, build-variant

For some reason, I can only run my app in **debug** mode but not **release** mode. Noticeably, there's a signing configuration for **debug** but not **release**. What's the correct way to create one for **release** so that the app can be deployed in **release** mode?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this solution.
https://itecnote.com/tecnote/android-studio-3-5-2-error-the-apk-for-your-currently-selected-variant-app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed/

Answer (score 0):

This quetion is already asked so you can check my solution at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76992063/14972910